Is there a way to dynamically get all WebAPI dom events and related types?
I want to get a list of all events like MouseEvent and related types, for example MouseEvent -> click, dblclick, mousedown, mouseenter, mouseleave, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, or mouseup
And what about the constructor? When I try to create a new BeforeUnloadEvent event, I get the error "Illegal constructor", How to check which values are correct?
I've seen code trying to do the same using regex mapping types to constructors, but it's not dynamic and browser dependent

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

I get that, but document.createEvent("BeforeUnloadEvent") works correctly unlike new BeforeUnloadEvent(), why? How does it construct this event and determine the proper constructor?
